# Technical information missing in "F1" screen for grid column of CL_SALV_TABLE

Tags: abap, alv

FM '**REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY**' allows user to get Technical information of structure name and Field name, after pressing F1 on a field of grid.

Is there any possibility to display technical information for grid of **CL_SALV_TABLE**?

regards,

Umar Abdullah

Comment: Both share exactly the same underlying technology, i.e. the "ALV grid control". Why would it behave differently? If it doesn't work in one of those 2 cases, probably that you didn't link the concerned field to the ABAP dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear rollname in fieldcatalog. sample example as below.

```
* Get the column object to Optimize
 DATA(lo_cols) = lo_salv_table->get_columns( ).
 lo_cols->set_optimize( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>true ).

* Change fieldcatalog
 DATA(lt_columns) = lo_cols->get( ).

 LOOP AT lt_columns ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_column>).

   <ls_column>-r_column->set_f1_rollname( value = '' ).

 ENDLOOP.
```

regards,

Umar Abdullah